# Parameters for newly-defined shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to declare a new shape in TikZ using `\pgfdeclareshape`. This shape will be formed from several parts, but often, when invoking the shape, I won't want all of the parts displayed. It would be ideal if I could pass some parameters or options when invoking the shape, and draw the shape differently in `\backgroundpath` depending on the parameters that are passed. Is this possible?

The anchors won't depend on the parameter, just which parts of the backgroundpath are drawn.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what `\pgfkeys` is for!  You can set various options in the `\pgfdeclareshape` pieces that look at the settings of various keys and act accordingly.

As an example, in my [TQFT Package](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/files), I have keys that set the number of incoming and outgoing boundary components and the shape is drawn accordingly.  Other keys control the style of the various pieces and determine which are drawn and which are not.

To do exactly what you want, you could define a new conditional key.

```
\newif\ifdrawnodepieces
\pgfkeys{/tikz/my shape/drawnodepieces/.is if=drawnodepieces}
```

Then in the `\pgfdeclareshape` code you have:

```
\ifdrawnodepieces
Code if set
\else
Code if not set
\fi
```

More complicated things are possible, such as changing the style of the path according to the settings.  You could save a style (make sure you initialise it in the preamble):

```
\node[my shape,my shape/path/.style={fill,draw,red,line width=5cm}] {};
```

and then invoke it in the shape:

```
\pgfsys@beginscope
  \tikzset{my shape/path}
  \tikz@mode
  \tikz@options
     draw path (using \pgfpath commands)
  \edef\tikz@temp{\noexpand\pgfusepath{%
      \iftikz@mode@fill fill,\fi%
      \iftikz@mode@draw draw\fi%
  }}%
  \tikz@temp
  \pgfsys@endscope
```

If you use TikZ-type commands in your shape (*not* recommended) then you can just invoke the style directly:

```
\path[my shape/path] (0,0) -- (2,0);
```

It is even possible to change the anchors of the node according to the parameters - I do this in the aforementioned TQFT package but I stole the idea from `pgflibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex` where the number of sides of a regular polygon depends on a parameter, and since each side gains an anchor then that must also vary.

Comment: Stumbled upon this answer and would like to adapt it for some cargo cult programming.  What do `\tikz@mode` and `\tikz@options` do here?  They aren't listed in the manual.

Comment: @HenryDeYoung That might be worth a question of its own.  They're useful things to know about (and I don't claim to know them fully) and a good explanation with examples would take up more than a comment could hold.